# Trying to understand flux in terms of Divergence Theorem

Tags: calculus

Hi I'm trying to understand the equation. Honestly, I don't know what $d\vec S$ is. And also I noticed that the $d\vec S$ on the divergence theorem equation is a vector form, while the $dS$ in the solution below isn't (where it says $\vec F.\vec n d S$)

I know the cross product of two vectors is right-angled to each other (the normal vector of a surface), but I don't know what $\vec r_{r}$ and $\vec r_{\theta}$ represent. Seeing the solution I know their cross product represent the normal of the surface, but I just don't know why it is so.

I understand when it does $\vec F.\vec n$ because it wants the component of the vector field on the normal vector, but what is the $dS$ after it? Why do we multiply the component with $dS$? So what's $d\vec S$ and $dS$ ?

[image: Here's the image of my question and part of its solution]

Comment: You should look at the Wikipedia page on [Flux integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral).  I'm voting to close because going through exactly what is meant by each element of a flux integral would be too long for a good answer and the information is available in *any* multivariable textbook.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf{r}_r$ and $\mathbf{r}_\theta$ are defined by :

$$\mathbf{r}_r \equiv\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial r},\qquad \mathbf{r}_\theta \equiv \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta}.$$
These basis vectors are the tangent vectors of the curves (on the paraboloid) obtained by varying one coordinate, keeping the other fixed.

$\mathbf{dS}$ is a vector normal to an infinitesimal surface of surface area $dS$ hence :
$$\mathbf{dS} \equiv \mathbf{n}\ dS.$$
On the paraboloid with the $(r,\theta)$ coordinates $\mathbf{dS}$ is defined by :
$$\mathbf{dS}\equiv \mathbf{r}_r\times\mathbf{r}_\theta\ drd\theta.$$

For more information see [Orthogonal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_coordinates) on Wikipedia.